# Removing spurious parenthesis in `TraditionalForm`

Tags: boxes, traditional-form

I don't understand the following behavior (in v 9.0.1) of `TraditionalForm` regarding insertion of parenthesis.

Let us start with the a definition for `myfuncF` to make boxes in traditional form:

```
myfuncF /: MakeBoxes[myfuncF[a_, b_], TraditionalForm] := 
  RowBox[{"f(", Sequence @@ Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {a, b}], ","], ")"}]
```

Now look at what I get as output for the following two commands:

```
x myfuncF[a,b] // TraditionalForm
myfuncF[a,b] > 0 //TraditionalForm
```

[image: first case]

Notice that in the first case, an unnecessary pair of parenthesis is inserted for multiplication.

Now I modify the `MakeBoxes` definition by inserting a small space: (in LHS, change `RowBox[{"f(",…` to `RowBox[{" f(",…`):

```
myfuncF /: MakeBoxes[myfuncF[a_, b_], TraditionalForm] := 
  RowBox[{" f(", Sequence @@ Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {a, b}], ","], ")"}]
```

Run the two commands again, and look what we get:

[image: second case]

Now we get an unnecessary pair of parenthesis in the inequality!

So my questions are:

1. How do I understand this odd behavior (what's going on behind the scenes)?
2. What can I do to get rid of these superfluous parentheses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us inspect the built-in behavior

```
ToBoxes@TraditionalForm[f[a, b]]

(* TagBox[FormBox[RowBox[{"f", "(", RowBox[{"a", ",", "b"}], ")"}], 
  TraditionalForm], TraditionalForm, Editable -> True] *)
```

So

```
myfuncF /: MakeBoxes[myfuncF[a_, b_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox[{"f", "(", RowBox@Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {a, b}], ","], ")"}]

x myfuncF[a, b] // TraditionalForm
myfuncF[a, b] > 0 // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

It is because `TraditionalForm` don't understand you and put parentheses for sure. They are necessary in the following example

```
plus /: MakeBoxes[plus[a_, b_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox@Riffle[Map[ToBoxes, {a, b}], "+"]

x plus[a, b] // TraditionalForm
plus[a, b] > 0 // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
myfuncF /: MakeBoxes[myfuncF[a_, b_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox[{"f", "(", RowBox[{ToString@a, ",", ToString@b}], ")"}]

x myfuncF[a, b] // TraditionalForm
myfuncF[a, b] > 0 // TraditionalForm
```

[image]