# Typesetting for different powers

Tags: formatting

Suppose that I want to typeset an object such that it looks
differently for different powers. The simplest example would
be a three vector. For odd powers I want it to look like $$|\vec{v}|^n,$$
while for even powers it should be just $$\vec{v}^n.$$

The naive approach

```
myvec /: MakeBoxes[myvec[x_], TraditionalForm] := 
 RowBox[{"|", OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "\[RightArrow]"], "|"}]
myvec /: MakeBoxes[myvec[x_]^n_, TraditionalForm] := 
 SuperscriptBox[
   RowBox[{"|", OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "\[RightArrow]"], "|"}], 
   ToBoxes[n]] /; OddQ[n]
myvec /: MakeBoxes[myvec[x_]^n_, TraditionalForm] := 
 SuperscriptBox[OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "\[RightArrow]"], 
   ToBoxes[n]] /; EvenQ[n]
```

obviously doesn't work, because the tag is too deep. A "dirty" hack
is to use

```
Unprotect[Power];
myvec /: MakeBoxes[myvec[x_], TraditionalForm] := 
  RowBox[{"|", OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "\[RightArrow]"], "|"}];
Power /: MakeBoxes[Power[myvec[x_], n_], TraditionalForm] := 
  SuperscriptBox[
    RowBox[{"|", OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "\[RightArrow]"], "|"}], 
    ToBoxes[n]] /; OddQ[n];
Power /: MakeBoxes[Power[myvec[x_], n_], TraditionalForm] := 
  SuperscriptBox[OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "\[RightArrow]"], 
    ToBoxes[n]] /; EvenQ[n];
Protect[Power];
```

This works fine but involves redefining protected functions,
which is something I'd really like to avoid. So, is there a safer and more
elegant way to achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tags (e.g. `Power /:`) are not necessary here. So

```
MakeBoxes[myvec[x_], TraditionalForm] := 
  TemplateBox[{OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "→"]}, "Abs"];
MakeBoxes[Power[myvec[x_], n_], TraditionalForm] := 
  SuperscriptBox[
    TemplateBox[{OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "→"]}, "Abs"], 
    ToBoxes[n]] /; OddQ[n];
MakeBoxes[Power[myvec[x_], n_], TraditionalForm] := 
  SuperscriptBox[OverscriptBox[ToBoxes[x], "→"], 
    ToBoxes[n]] /; EvenQ[n];

myvec[v] + myvec[v]^2 + myvec[v]^3 // TraditionalForm
```

> $ \left| \vec{v}\right| ^3+\left| \vec{v}\right| +\vec{v}^2 $

Here I use `TemplateBox[{...}, "Abs"]` to omit additional parentheses (see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63759/4678)). If you are interested in `TeXForm` and get redundant `\left\left` and `\right\right` see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/54857/4678).

Comment: Thanks! It looks like one actually never (or almost never) needs tags for typesetting, right?

Comment: @vsht It is good idea to use tags when you can. For example, it helps you to clear certain definitions with `ClearAll[yourTag]`.